# Lost access to system files and folders after changing admin password in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: permissions, passwords, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows 2008 R2 server (64bit) that is not part of a domain where a user that is part of the Administrators group began receiving an access denied message after changing the user's password. Windows would boot normally and show the desktop, but any attempt to open another instance of Windows Explorer or Control Panel or anything in the c:\Windows directory resulted in access denied.

Looking at the permissions of "c:\Windows" it appeared that administrators had no rights. I was finally able to use RunAsTI64 in order to launch a cmd.exe prompt with Trusted Installer permissions. This particular account was able to launch new instances of explorer and also successfully run icacls to add back Administrator permissions to the "c:\windows" directory.

However, even after permissions were re-added and it appeared like the Administrators group should have full control of the directory, I continued to receive access denied errors except when running with Trusted Installer credentials. I have already tried turning on and off UAC. To me it seems like this is some sort of Windows bug. Is there a patch that might fix this behavior? (I don't know if the computer was completely up to date with Windows Updates). Are there any other group policy / security settings that might apply?

It appears that one partial fix is just to reset the user's password back to the original password. After this is done the user magically regains access to everything. This doesn't solve the issue of how to change the password.

Comment: "Looking at the permissions of "c:\Windows" it appeared that administrators had no rights." - This is the default permission state of this folder.  The default permission of this folder only grants users in the User group read access.  "Is there a patch that might fix this behavior?" - There isn't anything to fix, so this patch, does not exist.

Comment: The user that happened to be an Administrator could not even execute Windows Explorer or read any files. Before changing the password, this user could execute files in the c:\Windows directory as well as read the files. Additionally after UAC prompting they could changing things (for instance they could run Control Panel). After changing passwords they couldn't even browse c:\Windows. As an Administrator they are still members of the Users group, right? @Ramhound

Comment: They are supposed to be.  If they are that's something you will have to confirm.